# Не создается окно Hello world, все компилируется без ошибок, но окна нет

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Не создается окно *Hello world*, всё компилируется без ошибок, но окна нет.

```
#include <windows.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hMainWnd;
    char szClassName[] = "FirstClass";
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(wc);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_CROSS);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = (LPWSTR)szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) 
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)L"Cannot register class!", (LPCWSTR)L"ERROR", MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    hMainWnd = CreateWindow(
        (LPCWSTR)szClassName, (LPCWSTR)L"A Hello1 Application ", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0,
        (HWND)NULL, (HMENU)NULL,
        (HINSTANCE)hInstance, NULL
    );

    ShowWindow(hMainWnd, nCmdShow);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hDC;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT rect;

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
        DrawText(hDC, (LPCWSTR)"Hello, mthrfckr!", -1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: это wiin forms?

Answer (score 0):

Во первых, вы используете при отображении окна в функции `ShowWindow (hMainWnd, nCmdShow);` в качестве второго параметра значение из входного параметра `nCmdShow` функции `WinMain()`. Вы уверены, что там находится не SW_HIDE (т.е. не 0), а хотя бы SW_SHOWNORMAL (1) или SW_SHOW (5)? Попробуйте для проверки заменить `ShowWindow (hMainWnd, nCmdShow);` на `ShowWindow (hMainWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);`

Во-вторых, у вас по тексту программы смешаны UNICODE-строки с ANSI-строками.
Такое, в принципе, возможно, но с определенными ограничениями: при вызове ANSI-варианта функции ей должны передаваться только ANSI-строки, при вызове UNICODE-варианта функции ей должны передаваться только UNICODE-строки.

В WinAPI (по крайней мере в основных библиотеках), все функции, которые работают со строками, существуют в 2 версиях: для ANSI-строк и для UNICODE-строк.

Таким образом, ваша функция `RegisterClassEx()` на самом деле существует в 2 вариантах:
в ANSI-варианте: `RegisterClassExA()`
и в UNICODE-варианте: `RegisterClassExW()`

В этом контексте "обычные" имена функций (без постфиксов A или W) являются лишь псевдонимами к одной из двух версий функции. В зависимости от настроек проекта или объявления/необъявления в заголовках вашей программы  `#define UNICODE` компилятор подставляет вместо "обычного" имени функции либо ее UNICODE-имя, либо ANSI-имя.

Из кода видно, что при регистрации класса в функции `RegisterClassEx()` в параметре `wc.lpszClassName` вы передаете ANSI-строку (`char szClassName[] = "FirstClass"`;), и тут же, далее по тексту при вызове других функций тоже в "обычном" виде (`MessageBox()`, `CreateWindow()`) вы передаете UNICODE-строки.

Такое однозначно не будет работать! Если у вас в программе по умолчанию используются ANSI-варианты функций, сбой будет в `MessageBox()`, `CreateWindow()`. Если UNICODE-варианты функций, то сбой будет в `RegisterClassEx()`.

Исправьте это:

1) либо сделайте все строки UNICODE или ANSI, и тогда в настройках / заголовках объявите UNICODE или ANSI вариант компиляции соответственно;

2) либо вызывайте напрямую функции с символами A / W на конце, передавая каждой из них либо только ANSI-строки (если используете A), либо только UNICODE-строки (если используете W).